# How to convert a sparse matrix to a dense matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a double sparse matrix shown below. My question is how can I convert it to normal matrix format?

```
s 
163840*1 sparse double

val =

                  (2,1)                     NaN
                     .
                     .
             (163823,1)                     NaN
             (163825,1)                     NaN
             (163827,1)                     NaN
             (163829,1)                     NaN
             (163831,1)                     NaN
             (163833,1)                     NaN
             (163835,1)                     NaN
             (163837,1)                     NaN
             (163839,1)                     NaN
```

Comment: I think you're asking for [full](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html).

Comment: If you copy&paste your question title exactly into google, the `full` doc is the first entry you get... I wonder whether you have tried that before?

Comment: @thewaywewalk: Actually I edited the title myself after the fact :) Still I agree the question was easily answerable with a simple search..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want the [full](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/full.html) command.

Answer (score 1):

`s_full=full(s);`
s_full is the dense matrix you want